# Listen to MouseEvents on certain text in a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, mouseevent, jlabel

I have a `JLabel` with `<html>` tag containing an hyperlink, which I want to attach a `MouseAdapter` to.
What I would like to do is to register a `MouseAdapter` to the `JLabel`, and inside it's methods check if the `MouseEvent` position is inside the hyperlink bounds.

Is there a way (maybe using `FontMetrics`?) to calculate the position of the hyperlink text inside the `JLabel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `JEditorPane` instead.  We can add an [`HyperlinkListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html) to that.

Comment: Anyway, can you think of a way to achieve it in a regular `JLabel`?

Comment: +1, @Elist, why reinvent the wheel? A JEditorPane was specifically designed for this.